# How to Determine a Post's Last Edited Date?

Tags: database, revisions

I'm writing a little extract script to do a DB pull. I've been asked to get all restaurant posts (custom post type) that are among the 1000 top hit, OR have been added or edited in the last 3 years. OK, so I've got the 1000 top hits done through an export from Google Analytics. Then I did a SQL extract like so:

```
SELECT p.ID, concat('http://www.toronto.com/restaurants/', p.post_name)
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'restaurant' AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_modified < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 36 MONTH);
```

I thought I had it licked. Then the users looked at it, and found some restaurants that I thought were outside the 3 yrs, which were in fact *inside*. On investigation, I found it was due to **revisions**.  :(

So, what is the best practice for determining last edited date, taking into account revisions?

Comment: So, you want to get all restaurant that were added or modified between now and 3 years ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, and you want posts created/modified between 3 years ago and today, try this query:

```
SELECT p.ID, concat('http://www.toronto.com/restaurants/', p.post_name)
FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type = 'restaurant' AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND p.post_modified > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 36 MONTH);
```

Because your `DATE_SUB` returns something like this: NOW - 3 years, so, it's something along the lines of `2011-09-20 12:21:41.000000`, and you are using a `<` sign, so you are checking for post that were created or modified before that date, so instead of getting the post created/modified between 3 years ago and today, you are getting the post created/modified more than 3 years ago.

Also, you aren't getting revision, because as you specify the `post_type = 'restaurant'`, and revision have a `post_type` called `revision`, you are just getting the post that belong to the custom post type you specified.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that lt gt issue. I feel very foolish. But about revisions: how do those work? So, if I make a change to a given restaurant, will WP create a revision record? And, if so, do I need to take the post_modified in the revision record into account? This is the real issue I'm trying to work out.

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster, no, the content to be shown is always of post type diferent to "revision". Revision are stored for each update or saved drafts. You can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions)

Comment: so the latest and greatest updates to a given post are always in the original record? The revisions are simply snapshots along the way. A backup of the previous version?

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster, I'm not sure I understand the first question, can you rephrase it?

Comment: Sure. When you update a post, the changes are saved in the original post record. But WP also saves the first instance of the record as a revision, so we can later go back to the original version. Yes?

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster, yes, you can read more about how do they work in the like I added in one of the comments